# What is the evidence for electrons interfering with each other, not just themselves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, interference, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

When electrons are passed one by one through a double slit experiment a diffraction pattern forms over time. As far as I can tell the same pattern forms if a beam of electrons is passed through the slits. If so, then the pattern formed by the beam can be entirely explained in terms of individual electrons interfering with *themselves*.

Is there evidence that electrons interfere with *each other* and if so from what experiment? As in, do they interfere with electrons *other than* themselves. I'm having trouble searching for this because I get back too many hits for the double slit experiment itself.

Comment: You said “As far as I can tell the same pattern forms if a beam of electrons is passed through the slits.” Do you have a reference or a source for this? I am skeptical that this is correct.

Comment: @Dale no, I do not. Nor can I find evidence that it is different, only that it exists. If the patterns are different then a reference would answer my question :)

Comment: @Dale why would this be controversial? The maxima are formed at $n\lambda = d\sin\theta$ regardless of the number of electrons per second passing through the slits.

Comment: @JohnRennie because electrons exert forces on each other. I certainly would not expect the same wave function for a single electron, with no forces acting on it, vs multiple electrons all repelling each other. Do you have a reference or a source that states that there is no difference?

Comment: @Dale the electrons are pretty widely spaced unless the beam current is high enough to melt the slits. While there will be some electrostatic interaction it's too small to make any noticeable difference to the diffraction pattern. Friends on mine worked on electron diffraction at the time I was doing my PhD and I do not recall any of them having to correct for interactions between the electrons in the beam.

Comment: @JohnRennie sure, but I believe that the point of the OP's question is precisely that situation where there are multiple electrons present and interacting. From what you are saying it sounds like there is indeed an interaction effect, it is just small for typical experiments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This turns out to be a surprisingly difficult experiment to do. To be absolutely sure you are seeing interference between different electrons you need two independent electron sources, and getting the two sources mutually coherent is very hard. As far as I know this was first achieved in 2007 as reported in [Interference between two independent electrons: observation of two particle Aharonov-Bohm interference](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0173) by Neder *et al*.

[A somewhat more accessible discussion of the paper is given here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Quantum_Tutorials_(Rioux)/Quantum_Optics/289%3A_Two-electron_Interference) though I'm afraid it is still considerably more complicated than the double slit experiment.

Comment: John, electrons are identical so how do you even define "different electrons"?

Comment: @DanielSank different momenta.

Comment: Ah, so different modes. That's an important distinction.

Comment: Thankyou. I don't entirely follow the maths, but I accept that it IS the answer. It suggests that electrons in a beam probably don't interfere with each other, except on very rare occasions, just because they are rarely coherent enough, but they should have a _probability_ of being coherent?

Comment: @AndyNewman electrons in a beam **do** routinely interfere with each other, but it's impossible to experimentally distinguish this from single electron interference. The reason the experiment is so hard is not because electrons don't interfere with each other, it's because finding a way to distinguish the mutual interference from single electron interference is so hard.

Comment: @AndyNewman if your question is can "the pattern formed by beam can be entirely explained in terms of individual electrons interfering with themselves"  then the answer is yes.  This is the famous Dirac comment for photons as well.  In general scientists think of electrons and photons as being independent events but in reality the EM field is full of many forces and interactions long before the photon leaves its atom ... i.e. the transmitting atom and receiving atom are already interacting.

Answer (score 0):

What is the double slit experiment  one electron at a time? It shows that the $Ψ^*Ψ$ of the experiment "electron +doubles σlits, given width and distance" ($Ψ$ the wavefunction) has the interference pattern of a sinusoidal function. Each electron scatters off the slits' collective field, and the slits collective field comes from electrons at the surfaces. So the double slit single electron at a time, shows interference effects of a single electron with the field of many electrons.

BTW an electron just by itself is a point particle in the quantum field theory of particle physics. "Interference " will always need an interaction , and boundary conditions for the solution of the quantum mechanical equation that defines a "*wave* function"